# Не работает функция asterisk DEVICE_STATE

Tags: asterisk

Суть в том, что нужно мониторить состояние каналов связи, по которым звонят на мобильные, используя при этом SIP-телефон и attendant консоль.
Напрямую через функцию состояние внешнего транка мониторить нельзя, поэтому предполагалось сделать так: звонок попадает в экстен виртуального сипа, который настроен сразу на звонок на мобильный, нужному устройству прописывается DEVICE_STATE=RINGING, и дальше идет собссно сам звонок.

```
exten => 101,1,Set(DEVICE_STATE(Custom:SIP/101)=RINGING)
exten => 101,n,Dial(SIP/79514585427@51321)
exten => 101,hint,SIP/101
```

Но на деле оказалось, что функция не срабатывает, даже если прописывать напрямую руками через консоль.

Модули перезагружала, по-идее, все должно работать, а по факту нет.

Comment: А вообще присваивается DEVICE_STATE какой-то? Попробуйте в виде эксперимента добавить в диалплан что-то наподобие `NoOp(${DEVICE_STATE(SIP/${EXTEN})})`. и просто проверить, будет ли получаться статус устройства.

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас SIP постоянно отвечает NOT_INUSE, то нужно добавить в [general] раздел sip.conf
callcounter=yes